# Net Core JWT Signing Credentials

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, jwt

I am following this tutorial: 
https://jonhilton.net/2017/10/11/secure-your-asp.net-core-2.0-api-part-1---issuing-a-jwt/

Here is the main code:

```
var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["SecurityKey"]));
                var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
                var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                    issuer: "yourdomain.com",
                    audience: "yourdomain.com",
                    claims: user.Claims,
                    expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),
                    signingCredentials: creds);
```

The part I don't understand is where it looks for a key in the configuration file, but it gives no indicator what this key is/should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This key can be any string: it's the secret key used to both encrypt and decrypt your secure payload.
From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric-key_algorithm):

> Symmetric-key algorithms are algorithms for cryptography that use the same cryptographic keys for both encryption of plaintext and decryption of ciphertext. The keys, in practice, represent a shared secret between two or more parties that can be used to maintain a private information link.

As for how to generate an efficient key, you can refer to this question on [crypto.stackexchange](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/29666).

Answer (score 1):

One option is to keep a repository of symmetric signing keys that are associated with the "kid" claim in the JWT header.  For example, keep a file of keys in an encrypted AWS S3 bucket.  The .NET Core 2 web service pulls the file of keys from the S3 bucket every X minutes.

When a request arrives, the "kid" claim value is used to look up the associated symmetric key from a collection that was built from the pulled file.

EXAMPLE:
Configure an IssuerSigningKeyResolver function.

```
public static IServiceCollection AddJwtValidation(this IServiceCollection services)
{
        IServiceProvider sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        ConfigRoot = sp.GetRequiredService<IConfigurationRoot>();

        tokenAudience = ConfigRoot["JwtToken:Audience"];
        tokenIssuer = ConfigRoot["JwtToken:Issuer"];

        SecurityKeyManager.Start();

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.Audience = tokenAudience;
            options.ClaimsIssuer = tokenIssuer;

            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {                    
                // The signing key must match!
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                RequireSignedTokens = true,
                IssuerSigningKeyResolver = MyIssuerSigningKeyResolver,
                ....
```

The IssuerSigningKeyResolver is defined as:

```
public static List<SecurityKey> MyIssuerSigningKeyResolver(string token, SecurityToken jwtToken, string kid, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
{
        List<SecurityKey> keys = new List<SecurityKey>();

        if (validationParameters == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("validationParameters");
        }

        if (jwtToken == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("securityToken");
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(kid))
        {
            SymmetricSecurityKey key = SecurityKeyManager.GetSecurityKey(kid);

            keys.Add(key);
        }

        return keys;
}
```

The SecurityKeyManager periodically pulls the key file from AWS S3 and stores the keys in a collection.

```
// Example approved-clients.txt file in the approved-clients S3 bucket (us-east-1).
//    //kid,key,active
//    customer1,AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA,true
//    customer2,BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB,true
//    customer3,CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC,true
//    customer4,DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD,true

namespace My.CoreServices.Security.Jwt
{
    public class SecurityKeyManager
    {
        private const int RELOAD_TIMER_DELAY_SECONDS = 3 * 1000;
        private const int RELOAD_TIMER_PERIOD_MINUTES = 60 * 60 * 1000;

        [DebuggerDisplay("{Kid}  {SymmetricKey}  {Active}")]
        internal class ApprovedClient
        {
            public string Kid { get; set; }
            public bool Active { get; set; }
            public string SymmetricKey { get; set; }
        };

        private static List<SymmetricSecurityKey> securityKeys = new List<SymmetricSecurityKey>();

        private static Timer reloadTimer = null;

        private static object keySync = new object();

        public static void Start()
        {
            // Start a new timer to reload all the security keys every RELOAD_TIMER_PERIOD_MINUTES.
            if (reloadTimer == null)
            {
                reloadTimer = new Timer(async (t) =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        List<ApprovedClient> approvedClients = new List<ApprovedClient>();

                        Log.Debug("Pulling latest approved client symmetric keys for JWT signature validation");

                        string awsAccessKeyId = JwtConfigure.ConfigRoot["AWS:KeyManagement:AccessKeyId"];
                        string awsSecretAccessKey = fromBase64(JwtConfigure.ConfigRoot["AWS:KeyManagement:SecretAccessKey"]);
                        string awsRegion = JwtConfigure.ConfigRoot["AWS:KeyManagement:Region"];

                        using (var client = new AmazonS3Client(awsAccessKeyId, awsSecretAccessKey, RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(awsRegion)))
                        {
                            var request = new GetObjectRequest();
                            request.BucketName = JwtConfigure.ConfigRoot["AWS:KeyManagement:Bucket"];
                            request.Key = JwtConfigure.ConfigRoot["AWS:KeyManagement:Key"];

                            var response = await client.GetObjectAsync(request);

                            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.ResponseStream))
                            {
                                while (sr.Peek() > 0)
                                {
                                    string line = await sr.ReadLineAsync();

                                    // Ignore comment lines in the approved-client file
                                    if (!line.StartsWith("//") && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
                                    {
                                        // Each line of the file should only have 3 items:
                                        // kid, key, active
                                        string[] items = line.Split(',');
                                        approvedClients.Add(new ApprovedClient()
                                        {
                                            Kid = items[0],
                                            SymmetricKey = items[1],
                                            Active = Boolean.Parse(items[2])
                                        });
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        }
                        lock (keySync)
                        {
                            if (approvedClients.Count > 0)
                            {
                                // Clear the security key list and repopulate
                                securityKeys.Clear();

                                foreach (var approvedClient in approvedClients)
                                {
                                    if (approvedClient.Active)
                                    {
                                        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(approvedClient.SymmetricKey));
                                        key.KeyId = approvedClient.Kid;
                                        securityKeys.Add(key);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        Log.Information($"Reloaded security keys");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Log.Warning($"Error getting current security keys - {ex.Message}");
                    }
                }, null, RELOAD_TIMER_DELAY_SECONDS, RELOAD_TIMER_PERIOD_MINUTES);
            }
        }

        public static void Stop()
        {
            if (reloadTimer != null)
            {
                reloadTimer.Dispose();
                reloadTimer = null;
            }
        }

        public static SymmetricSecurityKey GetSecurityKey(string kid)
        {
            SymmetricSecurityKey securityKey = null;

            lock (keySync)
            {
                byte[] keyData = securityKeys.Where(k => k.KeyId == kid).Select(x => x.Key).FirstOrDefault();

                if (keyData != null)
                {
                    securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(keyData);
                    securityKey.KeyId = kid;
                }
            }

            return securityKey;
        }

        private static string fromBase64(string encodedValue)
        {
            byte[] decodedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encodedValue);
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decodedBytes);
        }
    }
}
```

Ensure that when a JWT is created for a specific user/customer/etc, the "kid" claim is set in the JWT header.

```
{
  "alg": "HS256",
  "kid": "customer2",
  "typ": "JWT"
}
```

The value of "kid" will be passed as the third parameter to the IssuerSigningKeyResolver method.  That kid will then be used to lookup the associated symmetric key that is used to validate the JWT signature.